# loading="eager" does not work Chrome Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have an Angular App, which is displaying lazy loading articles as a masonry grid with a lot of images. When scrolling down the app reloads new items at a certain position. The lazy loading is only implemented via JavaScript and works as it should. But when the app loads 24 articles new articles and you scroll further, Chrome does not immediately load the 24 new images - it only loads the images, when visible in the viewport. I did some research and thought it can be solved with `loading="eager"` attribute on the `<img>` tag, but that doesn't change anything. Another idea was to preload the images as described [here](https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/), but I also don't know how to realise that with dynamic loaded image paths on scroll...

Comment: Does the rendered HTML include `loading="eager"`? If so, then angular may have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Yes it does... And yes Angular might not be the problem here, but maybe Angular offers a good solution for this, that I don't know yet.

Comment: `loading="eager"` is a browser issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading - I don't think Angular can help here

Comment: But do you know an alternative to preload images?

Comment: Use the `link` element with the attribute `preload`? https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/ - I've not tried this

Comment: Me neither in Angular with dynamic content - maybe someone else can explain...